# Need a auto click off tool to automatically click on OK button of popup window in Linux

Tags: linux, user-interface, automation

I need a tool similar to [ClickOff](http://www.johanneshuebner.com/en/clickoff.shtml) but this tool can work on Linux.

I tried several tools such as `xautoclick` but it is not what I want, I want to tool that can automatically click OK button when a popup window shows up (such as a webbrowser popup).

ClickOff works fine for me but the point is it cannot run on Linux. So anybody who knows such a tool or suggest me an approach so that I can write a tool like that on Linux. My Linux experience is modest, so please help me.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you.

> [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input
>   and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using
>   X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.
>
> There is some support for Extended Window Manager Hints (aka EWMH or
>   NetWM).

Something like this can be automated in a shell script *BUT* the bellow moves your cursor, so if you want it to run constantly like some background daemon you should save your original mouse coordinates and set it back afterwards... Personally I'd hate a something like this, as this steals your (window)focus...:

1. Search for the window by title:

   ```
   export WINID=`xdotool --onlyvisible --name YOURAPP`
   ```
2. gather further window information
   It is usually useful to know the window's height and width.

   ```
   WIDTH=`xwininfo -all -int -id $WINID|grep Width|cut -d ':' -f2 |cut -d ' ' -f2`
   HEIGHT=`xwininfo -all -int -id $WINID|grep Height|cut -d ':' -f2 |cut -d ' ' -f2`
   ```
3. Position mouse to window's top corner: to set the position of the mouse to 0,0 offset from the top-left of the window, first use

   ```
   xwininfo to determine window position...

   TOP_LEFT_X=`xwininfo -all -int -id $WINID|grep Absolute |grep X |cut -d ':' -f2 |sed 's/ //g'`
   TOP_LEFT_Y=`xwininfo -all -int -id $WINID|grep Absolute |grep Y |cut -d ':' -f2 |sed 's/ //g'`
   ```

   Now use those coordinates to position the mouse absolutely.

   ```
   xdotool mousemove $TOP_LEFT_X $TOP_LEFT_Y
   ```

   *NOTE*: With curved corner windows, clicking at this point may select another window, and de-focus
        your target.
4. You can calculate relative positions based on percentages, eg: using the 'bc' tool on the 
   command line:

   ```
   CENTER_X=`echo $WIDTH/2|bc`
   CENTER_Y=`echo $HEIGHT/2|bc`
   ```
5. Move the cursor:

   ```
   xdotool mousemove_relative $CENTER_X $CENTER_Y
   ```

   If you wanted the pointer centered horizontally, but 135 pixels above the bottom of the
   window:

   ```
   xdotool mousemove_relative $CENTER_X `echo $HEIGHT-135|bc`
   ```
6. Perform input:

   ```
   xdotool click 1
   ```